# How to change the value of "Configuration File (php.ini) Path"?

Tags: php, iis

I have 2 apps that use 2 different versions of PHP running in IIS. For each I have set the right module path and the loaded configuration file works and each app loads the correct configuration file, as seen in the `phpinfo()` output - each app has the correct (and different) `Loaded Configuration File` value.

However, the value above it, the `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` has "no value" for one of them, and `C:\Windows` for the other (But still it loaded the right `php.ini` as set by IIS)

I am using IIS, so I set the `PHPRC` environment variable for each of the php versions and that's why it loads the correct files even though it shows `no value` or `C:\Windows`:

[image]

I've read here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

But still, couldn't figure where does the `no value` come from for one PHP app, and where does the `C:\Windows` come from on the other PHP app, and can I change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`no value` is shown by phpinfo() whenever a configuration directive uses its default value, and on Windows, the `Configuration File Path` always uses the default of `C:\Windows`.

Comment: So why one shows `no value` and the other explcitly `C:\Windows`, and if no value was set, then how do they load the correct `php.ini` for each of the apps? Where do I need to set it?